# Weird file content format when editing from server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, formatting, hosting

Have anybody experienced this?

I have uploaded the file which is nicely formatted like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">

       <url>
          <loc>http://www.example.com</loc>
          <lastmod>2013-12-18T11:41:35+01:00</lastmod>
       </url>

       <url>
          <loc>http://www.example.com/something</loc>
          <lastmod>2013-12-18T11:41:35+01:00</lastmod>
       </url>

       ..
```

but after upload to the server I am getting this, when tring to open and edit that file directly from the server via WinSCP:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>



<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">



   <url>

      <loc>http://www.example.com</loc>

      <lastmod>2013-12-18T11:49:00+01:00</lastmod>

   </url>



   <url>

      <loc>http://www.example.com/something</loc>

      <lastmod>2013-12-18T11:49:00+01:00</lastmod>

   </url>

   ...
```

I have tried it multiple times and all files are affected.

Funny thing is that it probably adds new line breaks only after upload and not edit, because if I edit the file and delete the added lines and save it, it stays as I edited it.

I think it has something to do with the server, because this happens only on this one particular hosting.

I have never experienced something like that on other servers.

The client told me that they changed the server to something faster and probably it has some different PHP/Apache settings.

Did you experience similar problem.

What could be the problem? Could it be fixed in some PHP setting or Apache setting by the hosting company?

Comment: Are you editing on windows, then checking it from linux? They have different newline characters, that may be the cause.

Answer (score 0):

It is about end of line which is different in

- Linux LF "\n" - only newline character
- Windows CRLF "\r\n" newline and carriage return characters

You need to change it in your editor and then you won't have such problems.